# smbclient --authentication-file "session setup failed: NT_STATUS_INVALID_PARAMETER" and "SPNEGO(gse_krb5) NEG_TOKEN_INIT failed: NT_STATUS_NO_MEMORY"

Tags: samba

(I have Centos 7 with samba-client.x86_64 4.6.2-8.el7 against windows server 2008 that is in a AD Domain controlled by separate windows server 2008 AD domain controller)

Started with this:

```
smbclient -W my.domain -U myuser //svr.my.domain/fred mypassword -c list
```

... which worked great, then decided to move domain,user and password into a file and use -A as described in the smbclient manpage. File windows-credentials, content:

```
username=myuser
domain=my.domain
password=mypassword
```

... with command line:

```
smbclient -A windows-credentials //svr.my.domain/fred -c list
```

.... did not work, gave error:

```
SPNEGO(gse_krb5) NEG_TOKEN_INIT failed: NT_STATUS_NO_MEMORY
session setup failed: NT_STATUS_NO_MEMORY
```

... an hour on the internet suggested lots of people had this trouble and just about each had a different ticked answer, and none of them worked for me. Tried various combinations of their answers - in particular, https://askubuntu.com/questions/1008992/ubuntu-17-10-to-access-windows-files-shares-within-workplace-it, and ended up with...

Created a separate my.smb.conf with just:

```
[global]
  # seems to get rid of
  #   SPNEGO(gse_krb5) NEG_TOKEN_INIT failed: NT_STATUS_NO_MEMORY
  client use spnego = no
  # seems to get rid of
  #   session setup failed: NT_STATUS_NO_MEMORY
  client ntlmv2 auth = no
```

... and used:

```
smbclient -s my.smb.conf -A windows-credentials //svr.my.domain/fred -c list
```

... and it looks like it works, but I'm not really sure as there seems to be credentials caching and a complete lack of information on how this stuff works or is supposed to work.

Can anyone actually explain any of this? Even if not, perhaps yet another answer to this problem will help someone somewhere.

Comment: I have same problem but "smbclient -W my.domain -U myuser //svr.my.domain/fred mypassword -c list" return same error and solution did not work for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be specific to Windows 2008. Attaching to Windows Server 2016 works without the modified smb.conf file. I have been unable to locate any real details.

Comment: I agree that details are scant. I conclude that, surprisingly, "smbclient -A" works differently to smbclient specifying username, password, domain via explicit params.
The solution I settled on for my situation was to wrap smbclient in a shell script that accepts -A and simulates it by reading the file and passing the username, password and domain on to smbclient via -W etc. Someday I hope to look at the smbclient code to see what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

In case of problems with smbclient
you can mount smb folder and use it like local folder

```
mount -t cifs //<ip>/<share folder>$ /mnt -o user=<user>,pass=<password>,domain=<workdomain>
```